# How to integrate Qt software like FocusWriter, Telegram, Toggl Desktop or RStudio?

Tags: themes, 16.04, gtk, qt, qt5

What is required to integrate Qt applications such as [FocusWriter](https://github.com/gottcode/focuswriter), [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/), [Toggl Desktop](https://github.com/toggl/toggldesktop/issues/1622#issuecomment-215328326) or [Telegram Desktop](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/01/install-official-telegram-desktop-app.html) into the design of Ubuntu?

By default, these applications look as follows on Ubuntu 16.04:

**Telegram File Chooser Dialog:**
[image]

**FocusWriter Menu Bar:**

[image]

**RStudio Menu:**
[image]

**Toggl Desktop:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you find a way to change, at least, the font, f.i. in Toggl? It's not matching the global OS font: http://i.imgur.com/o1dhghP.png
Installing `qtconfig-qt4` didn't help either.

Comment: Sadly not. You have to make the developers aware to make them use the proper libraries, I am afraid. I don't believe this is a client-side problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that those apps are all using Qt5. Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/748186/79691) workaround and it should help.

Unfortunately, Toggl remains unchanged. So it's definitely upon the Toggl developers to solve that. I've already opened a [bug report](https://github.com/toggl/toggldesktop/issues/2333) over there.