# Qt apps stopped inheriting GTK themes

Tags: gnome, themes, 15.10, gtk, qt

After a fresh installation of Ubuntu Gnome 15.10, Qt apps like [qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview) or [QuiteRSS](https://quiterss.org/) suddenly stopped inheriting the global GTK theme, in my case [Numix](https://numixproject.org/). The same is also true for the default Adwaita theme, so most likely it's not the theme's fault. It seems, that these apps always use the Cleanlooks Qt theme, regardless of the present GTK theme.

I've never had any problems with theming on previous installations of Ubuntu Gnome.

Installing `qt4-qtconfig` and playing with different settings (GUI style: default, cleanlooks or gtk+) didn't have any effect on these apps.

Curiously, the `qt4-qtconfig` app itself is themed properly. So after selecting a different theme, e.g. "desktop settings (default)" or "windows", the theme of this app changes, but not in `qpdfview` or `QuiteRSS`. The trick with installing `libgnomeui-0` (mentioned [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications#Qt_applications_do_not_use_QGtkStyle)) didn't help either.

Does anyone experience the same and know of a workaround?

Comment: These might be Qt5 apps. Try installing `libqt5libqgtk2` as suggested [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/700220/vlc-2-2-1-using-qt-dialog).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On Ubuntu 17.10 Qt4 apps do inherit the global GTK theme, while Qt5 don't. Since `libqt5libqgtk2` isn't available in the official Ubuntu repositories anymore, we have to use another workaround:

Install `qt5-style-plugins` from the Ubuntu repositories with `sudo apt install qt5-style-plugins`.

Then add `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2` to `~/.profile` by `echo "export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2" >> ~/.profile`. This will theme all apps started as user.

If you prefer to apply the theming system-wide (for user and root apps), then use `sudo sh -c "echo 'export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2' >> /etc/environment"`.

For Ubuntu 20.04 – 20.10 you have to `sudo apt install appmenu-gtk2-module`, so that qt apps don't start with a delay. In Ubuntu 21.04 you don't have to install `appmenu-gtk2-module` any more.

I prefer this method over using [kvantum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233429/qt-apps-are-very-slow-to-load-in-xubuntu-20-04-when-export-qt-qpa-platformtheme/1234625#1234625), because with this method also root apps are themed properly and you don't have to adjust the theme in the kvantum manager, to match it your gtk theme.

Reboot and enjoy!

Comment: Excellent!!! [Xubuntu LTS](https://xubuntu.org/) should install this library by default!

Comment: This fixed the issue for me in Xubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: This solution is not recommended on newer systems: https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/712

Comment: Be sure to restart after installing `appmenu-gtk2-module`.