# How can I get Qt5 applications to use the GTK theme in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: themes, gtk, qt

Since I updated to Ubuntu 17.04, Qt5 applications (such as Qt Creator) won't use the GTK theme anymore. I tried to change this using *qt5ct*, but it only has the styles *Fusion* and *Windows* available, even though that the package `qt5-gtk-platformtheme` is installed.

How can this be fixed?

Edit: I'm using Unity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The look and feel of Qt5 applications is determined by platform themes and styles. The platform theme is responsible for icons, fonts, etc. and the style controls how widgets are rendered. I think you'll find your application such as Qt Creator is using the GTK3 platform theme as standard.

The problem has occurred since Qt5.7. In this release, the GTK2 platform theme and style was removed and replaced with the GTK3 platform theme. I've recently been in discussion with the Qt developers and it appears there isn't a GTK3 style to complement the platform theme and there are currently no plans to implement this in the future. Therefore, on Ubuntu, the default style is "Fusion" using the GTK3 platform theme.

There are a couple of methods to add a native style as follows:

1. The old GTK2 platform theme and style are still available in a separate package called `qtstyleplugins` that can be downloaded [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtstyleplugins.git/). Unfortunately, the GTK2 style is not compatible with the GTK3 platform theme. If you want to use the GTK2 style you will have to use the GTK2 platform theme. This will mean your dialogs etc. do not look native in Ubuntu 17.04. However, you may prefer it to "Fusion".
2. You didn't state what desktop environment you are using. There is a third party platform theme and style called `QGnomePlatform` available [here](https://github.com/MartinBriza/QGnomePlatform) and `adwaita-qt` available [here](https://github.com/MartinBriza/adwaita-qt). This provides a fully native look and feel when using Ubuntu Gnome.

For Qt Creator, I'm not 100% sure if it uses global theme/style locations. You may have to install them in `{Qt_installation_folder}\Tools\QtCreator\lib\Qt\Plugins\platformthemes\` and `{Qt_installation_folder}\Tools\QtCreator\lib\Qt\Plugins\styles\`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I wouldn't mind Fusion so much if the font rendering would not be so horrible. Is there an open bug somewhere about this?

Comment: The fonts have not appeared poor from what I've seen on my system. Do you have a screenshot of this?

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot here: http://imgur.com/a/u34W6
Left is Qt Creator, right is a vim session in gnome-terminal. I agree that is very subtle, but the Qt fonts just feel blurry (or blurrier?)  to me. Both applications are set to Ubuntu Mono 12.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I agree it's subtle. Sorry, don't know what to suggest on that one.

Comment: In case you are interested: I've had better results with infinality on funtoo, but as far as I know this patchset isn't properly maintained anymore. Anyway, the fonts look much better on my laptop, which has an IPS panel, so maybe I just need to upgrade my 7 year old display on my desktop. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9):

Apart from `qt5ct` you also need to install `qt5-style-plugins` package, then you should get the 'gtk2' theme in qt5ct

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-style-plugins
```

And, as per the [qt5ct documentation](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/11/configure-qt5-application-style-icons.html), don't forget to set `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct` in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/56xubuntu-session` and/or `/etc/environment`

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/748186/79691) answer works for me, without installing `qt5ct`.

Comment: yes, installing only qt5-style-plugins (i.e. w/o qt5ct) works just fine for styling qt5.7+ with gtk2. qt5ct is only needed if you want to also use other styles for qt5.7+ than gtk2

Comment: btw, being sick and tired of inconsistencies on my desktop, i ended up putting together a theme of my own, you might want to check it out if inconsistencies drive your nuts: http://xfce-evolution.sourceforge.net

Comment: This however stops working when you try to use wayland. I set `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct` and `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland` in `/etc/environment` and I can then use `qt5ct` to change the default themes that come preinstalled with `qt5ct`. Then I install `qt5ct-style-plugins` and new theme i.e. `gtk2` appears in `qt5ct` but it does not do anything when I select it!

Comment: **SUCESS!** After I installed `lxappearance` and choose the desired GTK2 theme *(any that are inside `/usr/share/themes`)* inside `lxappearance` , chosen theme was automatically adopted by `qt5ct`. This was the missing step! Well `qt5ct` did automatically adopt the theme even without `lxappearance`, but default theme was ugly! This also works for pyqt5 applications like `convertall`!