# Unable to change QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME environment variable

Tags: xfce, environment-variables, qt5

*Xubuntu 20.04 LTS*

I want to change default XFCE theme for Qt applications. It's set to `Fusion` style on my app. I read from tutorials that I need **kvantum manager** and **qt5ct**

I installed both packages without any problems, both are working fine.

So when it comes to overriding environment variables I placed it in 3 different locations:

1. `.profile`

```
echo "export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct" >> ~/.profile
```

2. `/etc/environment`

```
cat /etc/environment

# [...]
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct
```

3. autostart script

```
# [...]
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct
```

4. `.bashrc`

```
# [...]
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct
```

I placed it in every location that I know off, still **qt5ct** is telling me that, it has wrong configuration and `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2` is still set, so it has default system value as it had.
[Message from qt5ct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qugWP.png)

Tell me is it so different in Xubuntu? Because I previously had done that on ArchLinux without any of this issues. Does Ubuntu has some own environment variables file?

Answer (score 1):

you have to go to session settings go to advance and in environment variable add another one and set the name to be QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME and the value to qt5ct and then close session settings (make sure it gets save)
the next time you reboot qt5ct will work
that worked for me at least

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/952571, you need to install  `qt5-style-plugins`

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-style-plugins
```

and then set `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct` in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/56xubuntu-session`

Comment: ```/etc/X11/Xsession.d/56xubuntu-session``` Does this file exist, is it or should it be available after install? Because I do not have one on my system.

Comment: If it does not exist, you can make that file in that directory.