# How to make Okular follow the system theme?

Tags: themes, okular

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, Okular doesn't follow the Adwaita-dark or Arc themes when I set them with the Gnome tweak tool. Is there any way to fix this? All I really want is for Okular to use dark colors for its menus and toolbars.

Edit: When I try

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=Adwaita:dark okular
```

from the terminal, I get a bunch of errors like

```
(okular:16699): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:58:15.581: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:137:54: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.
(okular:16699): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:58:15.587: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1839:9: Expected a string.
(okular:16699): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:58:15.590: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2913:17: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax
```

I've also tried downloading systemsettings and kde-config-gtk-style and activating the themes there, with no response.

Comment: You may want to read something like https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications because Okular is a qt application.

Comment: @DKBose Thanks, I tried looking it over. I was at least able to get some errors at the terminal. It seems like the themes haven't adapted to the latest version of gtk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What worked for me was:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-style-plugins
```

This is taken from the [ArchLinux documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications). It also recommends setting the `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2` environment variable, but I did not need that.

See also [this other AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24780/how-to-make-kde-applications-look-native-in-gnome/1044419#1044419), this solution applies to all KDE applications.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Both were necessary for me.

Comment: I had to add the environment variable to /etc/environment rather than .bashrc for this to work.

Comment: Does not change a thing. Are you sure the KDE applications are taking settings from that application?

Comment: This works on Debian + i3 too ! I had to set the `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2` but without reboot I don't think it has an effect. To make sure this works, just run `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2 okular` from a terminal and if it's your theme you're good ! When the user successfully logs in [...] PAM may instruct the DM to read the variables from /etc/environment. [src](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables)

Comment: Works on Fedora as well, but the package name there is `qt5-qtstyleplugins`

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/748186/897783) worked for me to make @SamuelPrevost's suggestion in comments permanent, Ubuntu 22.04LTS.