# Changing SMPlayer theme doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, themes, smplayer

I try to change SMPlayer theme but nothing happens. I installed via official PPA. I installed SMPlayer on another Ubuntu machine too but still can't change theme.

Is there a dependency to install or do SMPlayer themes not work in Ubuntu?

[image: https://preview.ibb.co/b5o4dT/sm.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the `smplayer-themes` package too. Open Terminal and run

```
sudo apt install smplayer-themes
```

Then choose a "Style" in *Preferences* > *Interface*.

Comment: it says smplayer-themes is already the newest version (2:17.3.0-1~xenial1

Comment: I chose but nothing happens all of themes are same basic theme. When i look themes on internet each of them has different colors. But in my machine all of them same. Style only changes interface icons

Comment: Yes i am not beginner ubuntu user. For example i tried to apply that theme https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-smplayer-theme  theme shows in list but when i apply nothing happens

Comment: Papirus is an icon theme, and it is a part of the `smplayer-themes` package now (SMPlayer v16.6 or later). You can choose Papirus in the "Icon set" option. It will just change the icons, *not* the colour and interface of SMPlayer.

Comment: SM Player is a qt app so https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044340/how-to-make-okular-follow-the-system-theme maybe helpful.

Comment: @DKBose True that, but after installing `smplayer-themes`, one would be able to choose "GTK+" as a "Style" in Preferences > Interface, and it integrates with the system application theme (GTK+ theme) nicely.

Comment: You are right @pomsky but it should also change background but in ubuntu nothing happens about background color. When i choose a dark theme icons doesnt appear or same appearance again

Comment: @cotut As I said before Papirus would only change the icons. If you want to have dark background as in the link you provided you'll have to choose "GTK+" as a "Style" in Preferences > Interface and change your global GTK+ theme to  a dark variant. In the screenshot in the link you provided, I suspect the user uses "Arc Dark" GTK+ theme.

Comment: Thanks so much got it.  I managed to change background color but themes still not as in internet. I decided use skinnable gui.