# How to integrate Okular with the DE theme in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, okular

I have used Okular for many years. So far it has always seamlessly integrated with whatever DE theme I have set. It has functioned like this across many different Ubuntu releases, but not the latest:

[image]

I have searched in the preferences menus, but can not find an obvious way to tweak Okular's theme to the DE. How can it be done?

Comment: Does https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044340/how-to-make-okular-follow-the-system-theme help?

Comment: I installed the `qt5-style-plugins` package but nothing changed.

Comment: The proposed solution does not work with Okular installed via snap, but works if Okular is installed through sudo apt install okular

Answer (score 1):

For me installing the `qt5-style-plugins` and adding `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2` to `/etc/environment` (rather than `~/.bashrc`) did the trick.

Comment: I tried this but had no effect. Did you have to restart your DE?

Comment: I do not remember exactly, but I might very well have restarted the whole computer. If I am not mistaken /etc/environment is only read at login.

Comment: I tried restarting the DE and rebooting the system, but still Okular does not integrate with the theme. Perhaps you did something more than this?

Comment: I tried it again on a different PC. After performing the steps above it didn't work. I installed ´systemsettings´ (a KDE utility), but did not change anything. I then restarted and okular integrated with Gnome. I do not think the systemsettings step is necessary.

Comment: As you can see in the picture above, I do not work with GNome. But still strange that Okular integrates with GNome and not with Unity.

Comment: Ah.. I didn't realise that. I thought Gnome was default on 18.04.

Comment: I now had the opportunity of testing this solution with the GNome DE: it does not work either. I expect a solution that works on one to also function on the other. There must be still something missing from this answer.