# How to make Ubuntu feel more "integrated"?

Tags: themes, gtk, gtk3, mono, appearance

This screenshot shows different apps being shown very different. I'm showing keepass2, keepassx, keepassxc, with the theme "Yaru-dark".

What do I need to do to make they all look "dark"?

[image: Different apps showing very different]

Comment: Keepass2 uses Mono; the others use QT, so the issue there is probably something along the lines of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/748186/29073) where QT5 doesn't have a GTK[3] theme installed.