# Why does forcing Qt applications to use GTK theme makes those apps startup slowly?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, qt

I noticed whenever I force qt applications to use any GTK theme on Ubuntu 19.10 by adding the line `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2` to `.profile`, the startup time goes from 1-3 seconds to 20+ seconds for *vlc* and *qbittorrent*. Why is this and is there anything I can do?

I have ran 
sudo apt install qt5ct
and
sudo apt install qt5-style-plugins

Comment: Could you try `sudo gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache` if it helps?

Comment: When I used the **QT5 Settings** tool, I didn't see any delays after selecting the *gtk2* style.

Comment: Even using qt5 settings tool I get the same result.

Comment: What pacakge is gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders? Becuase I don't seem to have it installed.

Comment: I tested it with vlc and qbittorrent and it is like this with all themes.

Comment: @d-air1 And when you reply in comments, please *ping* the person you're replying to by using `@` followed by the first letter(s) of the user's name. Otherwise, they may not be notified that you've responded. Also, please add any additional information by [editing your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1185372/edit) as well.

Comment: I tested dolphin, featherpad, gwenview, kate, konsole, and vlc after setting `gtk2` in qt5ct's GUI and setting Adwaita-dark in Tweaks. No lag. I didn't use the `.profile` route. OS: Ubuntu 19.10. All packages installed using `sudo apt install`.

Comment: @DKBose also thanks for telling me how to ping people.

Comment: @DKBose I have installed qt5ct and qt5-style-plugins and have tried with adwaita-dark to no avail.

Comment: But does the application use the gtk theme when it eventually loads?

Comment: If the qt applications do use the desired theme, I can't explain the lag you see. Sorry!

Comment: @DKBose Yes you are correct it does use the theme when the application eventually loads.

Comment: @DKBose and it is alright It seems I can change the color palette withing qt5settings gui to something close enough and it will load that just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some testing as I had some machines with the problem and others without it. I have narrowed it down to this:

```
sudo apt install appmenu-registrar vala-panel-appmenu-common
```

With those both installed (and the recommends from appmenu-registrar), after reboot your qt5 apps should launch without delay, even with QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2 in your `~/.profile` or `/etc/environment` So GTK theme looks good plus no delay in launching qt apps!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk2-module` is sufficient, like described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/748186/79691

Comment: @DMT Not for me, on mint 20.01 (based on ubuntu 20.04), appmenu-gtk2-module was not enough, and needed to install these too.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu based Pop OS this same issue is occuring, but only on fresh 19.10 installs and not on 19.04 or 19.10 upgrades from 19.04. So if you had upgraded your system to 19.10 if the issue is not Pop OS specific then you likely won't experience the issue like those on fresh installs.