# GTK theme does not work properly on Qt Startup Applications

Tags: 20.04, themes, gtk, qt, autostart

#### Setup

When a Qt app (KeePassXC, AntiMicroX) is started automatically (via autostart), the GTK theme is not applied.

- All apps are installed via standard `apt` packages (I am aware of snap theming issues).
- I am on Ubuntu `20.04`, I use the Yaru dark gtk theme.
- To apply the GTK theme onto Qt apps, I did the following:

  - Installed the `qt5-style-plugins` apt package (with all of its dependencies)
  - Added a line to `/etc/environment`: `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2`
  - This works properly if I start the applications manually

Additional fiddling showed, that on cold start the theme never gets applied properly, however, on a restart, it does work sometimes.

#### Questions

- How can I ensure that the dark gtk application theme gets properly used?
- I would assume that when the autostart happens, some setting is not loaded, hence the breakage.
  Is there some sort of *"service"* those apps would have to wait for?
- Should I try to add delay?

Comment: By any chance, are these installed as `snap`?
Edit your question to add this information

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi No - standard apt installs. `snap` theming is a different problem I gave up on (some say its work in progress)

Comment: The mentioned apps are qt-applications, not GTK...

Comment: Check out the package `qt5ct`, it's a qt5 configuration tool, that might be helpful for you.

Comment: I should point out that Qt-based applications don't inherit GTK themes - they use Qt themes.  Just like GTK applications don't use Qt themes.  Known issue between those types of applications using different themeing mechanisms.

Comment: @mook765 Thanks, you were right - in the meantime I did some local testing. However, I had no success with qt5ct - the theme still does not apply properly with autostart. Do You know more about autostart and theming please share some sources!

Comment: Does it work when you add a startup delay? Also, there may be issues with qt5ct. You can try Kvantum, which is modern, and very actively developed. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1234625/124466

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What made it work

Added a 1 second startup delay to the autostart desktop files (in `~/.config/autostart/`):

```
[Desktop Entry]
...
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=1
```

This made the apps to start after the X session has properly initialized itself after login. Nothing else was needed (apart from the initial setup).

#### Notes

- The QT Configuration tool (shipped in `qt5ct` apt package) is viable but not necessary.

  - If installed it addes an X session config `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/99qt5ct` that sets the `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME` to `qt5ct` if unset.
  - It enables a wider configuration of Qt theming. I used a minimal `~/.config/qt5ct/qt5ct.conf`:

  ```
  [Appearance]
  icon_theme=Numix-Circle
  standard_dialogs=gtk2
  style=gtk2
  ```
- For debugging the env of the apps can be checked with this shell command (note, I use fish and not bash): `strings /proc/(pidof keepassxc)/environ | grep QT`
- To investigate where environment variables are set one can use these commands:

  ```
  # system wide - this was quick
  grep QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME --recursive /etc/*
  # per user - this was super slow on my system (*khm* steam *khm*)
  grep QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME --recursive ~/*
  ```
- **Sources:**

  - Comments under this question
  - [How to determine where an environment variable came from?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/823/229535)
  - [How can I delay a specific program on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/a/195036/469092)

Answer (score 0):

## On Xubuntu 20.04 LTS

First, install the Qt5 configuration tool with

```
$ sudo apt install qt5ct
```

Then, comment out the following line in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/56xubuntu-session` by inserting a hash up front:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/Xsession.d/56xubuntu-session
    # QT5 apps to use GTK style
    #export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2
```

Now, log out and in again. Changes made with `Menu` → `Settings` → `Qt5 Settings` will take immediate effect.