# Dolphin slow to start up

Tags: dolphin

Dolphin started taking a long time to start up a couple days ago.
I timed some starts (in seconds)

34 43 40 34 27 42

Some were started by command line, some by the icon on the application bar

```
~$ dolphin -v  
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
dolphin 19.12.3
```

The icon executes this command:
dolphin %u

I uninstalled and reinstalled Dolphin with no effect.

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

What can I do to see what is going wrong?

Comment: This is a known bug, use Kvantum instead of qt5ct.  https://askubuntu.com/q/1233429/124466

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt apps are very slow to load in Xubuntu 20.04 when export QT\_QPA\_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2 is enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233429/qt-apps-are-very-slow-to-load-in-xubuntu-20-04-when-export-qt-qpa-platformtheme)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I installed KVantum using the apt command given and then did the echo command but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that Ubuntu is using kvantum, and still not using qt5ct? Does the theme in Dolphin change when you change the theme in Kvantum manager? (then Ubuntu is using Kvantum). Does the theme in dolphin change when you change the theme in `qt5ct`? Then Ubuntu is still using `qt5ct`. (Enter the command `qt5ct` to open its settings window).

Comment: The theme in dolphin does not change when I change the theme in qt5.

Comment: I don't know why but a couple days and several restarts later, Dolphin starts up quickly once again.