# VLC Media Player not respecting GNOME theme settings

Tags: 20.04, themes, gnome-shell, vlc

Edit: Solved it following [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/748186/1221273) instructions.

---

I used to run Ubuntu MATE with the Dracula GTK theme, basically turned my entire OS into a dark theme environment.
VLC Media Player respected the theme settings, but then I decided to completely switch over to GNOME 3 because the theme looks way better there and I don't lose any performance anyway. The issue now is that VLC theme is light, while every other application is dark.

[image: VLC Media Player Screenshot]

My thoughts are that some configuration files have not been removed while I uninstalled the MATE environment, I didn't reinstall Linux from Ubuntu-MATE to Ubuntu-GNOME. I just switched desktop environments manually.

I have yet to encounter a similar problem in some other application but for now all others work fine.

Comment: This is because, VLC uses the QT toolkit, and won't follow the GTK theme by default. See this answer for a workaround to make the QT apps follow the GTK theme. https://askubuntu.com/a/748186/124466

Comment: You can click on `Close` and mark your question as a duplicate of the one I suggested.